# Is there a `when()` statement or some equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there maybe something like a "when" statement in C#?

The reason I want this is because an `if` statement only checks once if a certain property is `true` at a particular time, but I want it to **wait** until the property is `true`.

Anybody know something I can do in C# that would be similar to a "when" statement?

Comment: it's better to put your code for understanding your propose, but if i get your mean, it is `WHILE(true) { }`

Answer (score 6):

What you want is [SpinWait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait.spinuntil(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g. `SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => condition);`

It will sit there until it either times out (with your specified timeout) or the condition is met.

Comment: Using c# for 5 years and still coming across things I've never heard of!

Comment: If you want to waste electricity and make your computer do a lot of wasteful computations, this method is perfect.

Comment: There is that @TheGeneral, but you could always stick a sleep in the condition if you were waiting a while.

Comment: Do I need a certain "using" for this? I can't find it

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinwait(v=vs.110).aspx) : _SpinWait is not generally useful for ordinary applications. In most cases, you should use the synchronization classes provided by the .NET Framework, such as Monitor._

Comment: @TaW yes if there were two threads at play here (I dont know if there are) Id probably just use an auto reset event or something on the setter of that property

Answer (score 4):

There is no `when` control statement, but there are two options which might meet your needs:

You can use a `while(predicate){}` loop to keep looping until a condition is met.  The predicate can be any expression which returns true/false - as long as the condition is true, it will loop.  If you just want to wait without consuming too much CPU, you can Sleep() the thread within the loop:

```
while(name == "Sebastian")
{
    // Code to execute
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

If you property is a numeric range, you could use a `for` loop, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: I used this method, but it didn't execute the code inside the while loop

Comment: Did you change the example `name == "Sebastian"` to what you need it to be?  Remember it will go into the loop every time the condition is `true`, so you should setup you condition so that true means you want to wait again, and it be comes false when you condition is met.  Definitely goes into the loop if the condition is true - I just tried it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deal with an asynchronous world than you may be should look at the library [Rx.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive). Let's look at the simple example: suppose you want to read strings from the console and **when** user inputs word `"hello"` you need to print `"world"` in the response. This simple example can be implemented as follows:

```
var inputLines = new Subject<string>();
inputLines.Subscribe(info =>
{
    if (info == "hello")
        Console.Out.WriteLine("world");
});
while (true)
{
    var line = Console.In.ReadLine();
    inputLines.OnNext(line);
}
```

So, there are explicit **when** action, that we pass in the `Subscribe(...)` function.

In this simple example usage of `Rx.NET` is obviously unnecessarily and you shouldn't do it. But in more complex scenarios this is a very helpful library. You can see, that with Reactive Extensions you split the logic of your application from the main event-pool, where you can want to do some other work, not related to the application logic. Also, there is high flexibility that you can get with this library, because it's very dynamic - you can subscribe and unsubscribe different events in run-time at any time.

You can notice, that there is another way to solve my example in the event-based paradigm. We can simply use built-in events like this:

```
public static event EventHandler<string> InputEvent;
public void Run() 
{
    InputEvent += (sender, line) =>  {
        if (line == "hello")
            Console.WriteLine("world");
    };

    while (true) {
        var line = Console.In.ReadLine();
        InputEvent?.Invoke(this, line);
    }
}
```

And this is a right point, sometimes you can replace Reactive Extensions with simple events because they are connected. But when you need to build a complex pipeline from many event sources and using many different tightly coupled actions, then Reactive Extensions allow you to nicely build this pipeline in the very declarative way.

Comment: Nice solution with .Net events. But the recommended way is to use `EventHandler` for the delegate and derived class from `EventArgs` if you want to pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'async' and 'await' to wait unit a certain 'Task' is complete. 'await' is somewhat similar to the 'when' statement you need.  Only it pauses the current 'Task' until the awaited 'Task' finished with *any* result not just when an expression becomes 'true'.  See also [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think you go to far by giving a solution with `Task`. Simple `while(predicate)` is sufficient here I think.

Comment: It very much depends on the OP's a 'while' loop may result in a busy wait.  I assumed that 'when' implied waiting for some other part of the same process set some condition to true, therefore tasks or threads.

Comment: If you need to wait for some asynchronous event then you can consider library `Rx.NET` for dealing with this task. We can create some observable subject corresponded to our event and subscribe some specific action to it.

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here? Are you running a synchronous process or are you waiting for something asynchronous to happen?

**If you're synchronous** then `while` is probably the correct solution:

```
var result = 0;
while(result != 6)
{
    result = RollADie();
    Console.WriteLine($"I rolled a {result}");
}
Console.WriteLine("At last, a six!");
```

But - **if you're waiting for something asynchronous** to happen then a different solution is called for. An asynchronous scenario is where you want your code to 'hang around and wait, doing nothing' until the condition is fulfilled.

In that case the modern C# solution is asynchronous programming using the `async` and `await` keywords, along with the `Task` class (and it's generic cousin `Task<TResult>`). That's probably a bit deep to go into here, but [here's a pretty good primer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

What's important is that you *don't use a solution based on `while`* in order to deal with asynchronous processes. You'll just send the CPU spinning in circles, chasing it's own tail so to speak, when really you want to say "now stop working on this until X happens". Also, avoid any solution based on `while` combined with `Thread.Sleep` for related reasons.